# How to access CSS children properly?

Tags: html, css

If I want to change the background of the first 2 `<div>` in this HTML code inside the "main" `<div>`

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Is this the most optimal way to do this?

CSS

```
.main div:nth-of-type(1),
.main div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set ranges with `nth-child`. To start from a position (defined by the last part `+ 2`) and select all children that follow, use `n`, if you want to select all elements before the position, use `-n`. (Inclusive in both cases.)

More tips and tricks concerning `nth-child` [here](http://nthmaster.com/).

```css
.main div:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```